# How use custom validation on forget password in Partner Portal

Tags: administration, partner-portal

i have requirement where we need to add custom validation when a partner user forgets password and clicks on ***forget password*** link, and partner will be asked to enter the username so that they will receive a password reset link.So the requirement is to run few validations before the reset link is sent to the Partner. Can we do this using custom apex code? if so please mention the steps how to achieve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom forget password controller in Apex to control your behavior.

Here is the source URL for the same.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm